# android - design percentage bar like battery doctor

Tags: android, progress

I am trying to make semi circle chart like this one, are there any libraries do this?

I found this one, but this isn't what I want.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: can you post some code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the [library](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) that you need.

Comment: it very close to mine

Comment: Use the attr arc_angle for complete your half circle

Comment: can I animate this chart

Comment: All are animate when the percent is loading. But of course, you can use onProgressUpdate for do this.